# how to dismiss the keyboard, when you finish typing in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I am writing a simple code, as below,,,,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    restaurant_name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 83, 135, 21)];
    [restaurant_name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [restaurant_name setText: @"Restaurant Name"];
    [self.view addSubview:restaurant_name];

    restaurant_name_textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 80, 150, 31)];
    [restaurant_name_textfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [restaurant_name_textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [restaurant_name_textfield resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view addSubview:restaurant_name_textfield];

    restaurant_name_save = restaurant_name_textfield.text;
    //NSLog(restaurant_name_save);

    picker_delivery = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 113, 110, 25)];
    [picker_delivery setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [picker_delivery setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18]];
    [picker_delivery setText: @"Pick/Delivery"];

    [self.view addSubview:picker_delivery];

    amount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 153, 150, 20)];
    [amount setText: @"Amount"];
    [amount setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:amount];

    amount_textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,150 , 150, 31)];
    [amount_textfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [amount_textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:amount_textfield];

    ready_in = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 188, 150, 20)];
    [ready_in setText:@"Ready in"];
    [ready_in setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:ready_in];

    ready_in_textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 185, 150, 31)];
    [ready_in_textfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [ready_in_textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:ready_in_textfield]; 

    reminder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 230, 150, 20)];
    [reminder setText: @"Reminder"];
    [reminder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:reminder];

    mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 230, 50, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch];



    start_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [start_button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 100, 50)];
    [start_button setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[myButton setImage:myButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [start_button addTarget:self action:@selector(saveData) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        [self.view addSubview:start_button];


}



-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    return YES;
}
```

THis is Coding oF RestaurantViewController.m
but nothing is happening when I press Return key,

any Idea???

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your post to put your code into a code block. In future, when you paste code into a question, you want to hit the "{}" button to wrap it in a code block, or put four spaces at the left margin of every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .h file should have to be like this

```
@interface Book : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

UITextField *amount_textfield;

}

and your implementation file should be:

```
    - (void)loadView {

amount_textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 120, 200, 40)];
amount_textfield.delegate=self;
[ContentView addSubview:amount_textfield];}
```

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
return Yes;
}

Comment: @Veer - NO IT'S NOT. It looks like it is, but in fact the UITextField being allocated and stored in amount_textfield IS leaking. This will crash your application. Stop ignoring memory management.

Comment: @Veer - You have to release the textfield in dealloc.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your view controller adopts the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol. Then set the `.delegate` property of each of your UITextFields to `self`:

```
amount_textfield.delegate = self;
```

Also, EVERYTHING that you alloc and init needs to be `release`'ed. In this case, that should probably happen right after the `addSubview:` call that adds each such thing to the superview.

Comment: I adopted the <UITextFieldDelegate>, as written here                    @interface RestaurantViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: where should I write amount_textfield.delegate=self ?

Comment: Right before you add it to the subview will be fine. Then right AFTER you add it to the subview go: `[amount_textfield release];`. Otherwise that object will leak.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the delegates of the text fields to the controller? E.g., `restaurant_name.delegate = self`? You have to do this for all the text fields that require the keyboard to be dismissed when you press Return.

Comment: No, I didn't write anything like as you wrote here, where should I write it ?